# Issue executing Runtime.getRuntime().exec AWK

Tags: java, unix, awk

I want to execute following command:

```
 awk '{print "1" $0}' /path_toFile/file.txt
```

this is my code:

```
String[] params = new String[3];
params[0] = "/usr/bin/awk";
params[1] = "print \"1\" $0";
params[2] = "/path_toFile/file.txt";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
```

Getting Error:

```
Exit Value = 2
 syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                 >>> print <<<  \"1\" $0
 awk: Quitting
 The source line is 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is missing surrounding braces(`{..}`):

```
params[1] = "{print \"1\" $0}";
```

Comment: NO, another error: Exit Value = 2
 syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                {print >>>  \ <<< "1\" $0}
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.

Comment: @yuris, I don't understand why you get the error. It works for me. See this: http://asciinema.org/a/9842

Comment: @yuris, What OS are you using?

Comment: I think there is some issue with \

Comment: @yuris, Ah, actually `\"` is not needed. Try: `params[1] = "{print 1 $0}";`

Comment: ,what if I want to output to other file? `params[2] = "/path_toFile/file.txt>/path_toFile/file.txt3";`   didn't work

Comment: @yuris, redirection is a feature of shell. To use it, you need to pass the command to shell: `sh -c 'command ..... > output.txt'` (`sh` as the first argument, `-c` as the second argument, and rest)